# Image is not displaying in device in IONIC 4 from server in android version 9 and above

Tags: android, angular, image, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to show list of categories.

Image is not shown on android version 9  and above.
when I try to put static image it shows perfectly but image from server is not shown.

On ionic serve it is showing image as expected.

Response:

> [{"categoryId":"1","name":"General
>   Knowledge","image":"http://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/gk_categaries_icons.png"},{"categoryId":"3","name":"Biology","image":"http://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/biology_categaries_icons.png"},{"categoryId":"4","name":"Chemistry","image":"http://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/Chemastry_Categaries_Icons.png"},{"categoryId":"5","name":"Economy","image":"http://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/Economy.png"},{"categoryId":"6","name":"Sports","image":"http://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/sports_categaries_icons.png"},{"categoryId":"7","name":"Physics","image":"http://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/physics.png"},{"categoryId":"8","name":"World
>   Geography","image":"http://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/geo.png"},{"categoryId":"10","name":"Science
>   &
>   Inventions","image":"http://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/science.png"}]

**tab1.html**

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row  class="margin" *ngFor="let row of grid">
    <ion-col size="3" class="ion-text-center" *ngFor="let item of row" (click)="quizInfo(item.categoryId,item.name)">
      <img class="logo" [src]='item.image'> <br>
      <!-- <img src="../../assets/icon/bio.png" class="logo"> <br> -->
      <p class="margin title">{{item.name}}</p>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

This is my html for displaying list.

Image is not shown
1st image is of android version 9 and is android version 7

[image]   [image]

Comment: The image you added is saved in db in form of http://... or just image name?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is http request.
Image path start with http.
Android pie don't accept API requests without https requests for security.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that android 9 above by default only accepts HTTPS calls. But you can bypass
add this to your `Androidmanifest.xml`: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" // -->here
    android:allowBackup="true"
    ...
    >
```

But its recommend to use only HTTPS